# Permission denied when execute bash script from php (apache2)

Tags: php, bash, google-cloud-platform

I have to run a bash script from php (apache webserver). The bash script contains google sdk commands and when I try to execute them I receive this error in the apache logs: "Permission denied". I have already modified the owner of the files with the apache user but nothing has changed.
The bash file work fine if I execute it on teminal and the GCE command are used whit absolute path

```
<?php
$n_clones = $_POST['clone_num'];
$n_processors = $_POST['core_num'];
if ($n_clones <= 0 || $n_clones >= 10) {
   exit("Wrong number of clones!\n");
}

if ($n_processors <= 0) {
   exit("Wrong number of processors!\n");
}

system("./clone.sh '" . $n_clones . "' '" . $n_processors . "'", $output);
echo $output . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Apache runs as a different user, and that account most likely does not have access to mess with your GCE account. The easiest way to work around this is probably to set up `sudo` to allow the Apache user passwordless access to impersonate your user when running the script.

Comment: Your problem is this line: `system("./clone.sh '"`. clone.sh is not a program. You must use this as an argument to a shell such as `bash`.

Comment: I made clone.sh executable with "chmod +x ...", so I can execute it in this way.

Comment: @Vincenzo adding that this was resolved?